# Keep only the rows with specific decimal values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Currently having a brain fart, I can't remember how to filter out numbers based on the decimal that they end with.

Say my data frame is-

```
dic = {'product':['Bread','Milk','Eggs','Water','OJ','Cereal','Coffee',
                    'Apples','Banana','Muffin'],
       'price':[3.89,2.99,4.00,0.69,1.99,2.39,5.00,0.99,0.98,1.50]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
print(df)
```

With output-

```
  product  price
0   Bread   3.89
1    Milk   2.99
2    Eggs   4.00
3   Water   0.69
4      OJ   1.99
5  Cereal   2.39
6  Coffee   5.00
7  Apples   0.99
8  Banana   0.98
9  Muffin   1.50
```

And I only want to keep prices ending in .99, .00, and .50

My desired output would be-

```
  product  price
1    Milk   2.99
2    Eggs   4.00
4      OJ   1.99
6  Coffee   5.00
7  Apples   0.99
9  Muffin   1.50
```

Should know how to do this, just can't remember currently.

Comment: Made some changes to your question to (hopefully) be more discoverable on google. LMK if the changes aren't to your liking. Thanks.

Comment: Changes work great. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If these are simple money (dollar) amounts, you can convert the decimal values to ints (to avoid floating comparisons, these may result in incorrect answers) and then make an `isin` check:

```
df[df['price'].mul(100).mod(100).astype(int).isin([0, 50, 99])]

  product  price
1    Milk   2.99
2    Eggs   4.00
4      OJ   1.99
6  Coffee   5.00
7  Apples   0.99
9  Muffin   1.50
```

This one is the faster of the two by my tests.

---

Another option with `np.isclose`:

```
df[np.logical_or.reduce([
    np.isclose(df['price'].mod(1), d) for d in [0, .99, .5]])]

  product  price
1    Milk   2.99
2    Eggs   4.00
4      OJ   1.99
6  Coffee   5.00
7  Apples   0.99
9  Muffin   1.50
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
dic = {'product':['Bread','Milk','Eggs','Water','OJ','Cereal','Coffee','Apples','Banana','Muffin'],
       'price':[3.89,2.99,4.00,0.69,1.99,2.39,5.00,0.99,0.98,1.50]}


for price in dic['price']:
    if str(price).split('.')[1] not in ['99','5'] and int(price)!=price:
        dic['product'].pop(dic['price'].index(price)) # Remove the product that aligns with the unwanted price
        dic['price'].remove(price) # Remove the price

print(dic)
```

Output:

```
{'product': ['Milk', 'Eggs', 'OJ', 'Coffee', 'Apples', 'Muffin'],
 'price': [2.99, 4.0, 1.99, 5.0, 0.99, 1.5]}
```